# How to Disable Internet Explorer Enterprise mode in IE

Tags: user-interface, internet-explorer-11, enterprise

I want to disable the site , that is loading in Enterprise mode .
I have checked the Register key settings and Group policy object ,
Under Register:
{HKLM|HKCU}\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer} the Main is not exists
and under GPO the Enterprise mode option is not available.

In both the place it is not configured. Any suggestions?. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, although unlikely, that the EnterpriseMode registry key is in  {HKLM|HKCU}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer (notice it's not in the Policy node).

Another possibility is that you have locally set the site to use Enterprise Mode. This is done by going to "Tools" -> "Enterprise Mode".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of the **Registry editor.**

1. Open a regedit.exe from "Run" and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode.
2. You will find keys against the Enterprise mode in the right hand side panel, such as DEFAULT, ENABLE and SITELIST.
3. You will need to DELETE the keys called ENABLE and SITELIST.
4. Run your application again on IE and test. You must have the result.

**NOTE**: This solution could be temporary as the registry adds those keys back after a system restart!